# Aligning wheels for heavy duty bike trailer

Tags: trailer, weight, diy, alignment

I'm planning to build a bike trailer capable of carrying about 120kg. My initial thought was to use decent quality double-walled 20" BMX front wheels with the axles supported on both sides. I'd align dropouts drilled into sheet steel in a wooden frame (a lighter version of this sort of plan: [www.instructables.com/Wooden-Bicycle-Trailer/](http://www.instructables.com/Wooden-Bicycle-Trailer/))

But I'm not sure how to get a good alignment. Maybe drill holes in my plates, then secure while they're held in relative position by a threaded rod running across the bottom of the trailer frame?

And maybe higher quality trailer wheels that just attach on the inside would be sufficient?

Comment: A trailer carrying 120 KG will absolutely need wheels supported on both sides.  

Single-sided wheelchair-style wheels are not going to cut it here.